# Free jqGrid 4.13.6 - Shared 'Query' with Advanced Filtering

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Suppose I have two different grids, were each have its own advance filter dialog.

What I noticed since the upgrade to 4.13.6 is the following:

1. The z-index of the dialog was reduced
2. The 'query' section within the dialog is being overwritten by any of the other open filter dialogs. It doesn't effect the actual operation, but the 'query' is shown wrongly, as it not belong to it.

In the example below, you can see that the top dialog is also changing the bottom dialog 'query'.

[image]

Was there any shared attribute added between the filters dialog so now they overwrite each other?

Thanks,

Tal.

Comment: Please don't use old version if a new one is published. The current version of free jqGrid is 4.14.0. Could you describe more details which "attributes" you need to "share"? It's good to describe the problem on an example. You should additionally post JavaScript fragments, which shows how you use free jqGrid or better to create the demo, which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. In the picture - two different filters. Each overwrite the query text of the other with every selection of an attribute. Seems like a bug.

Comment: I repeat my questions: do you verified that the same problem exist **in the latest version of jqGrid** 4.14.0? The version 4.14.0 includes many bug fixes (an of cause new features). For example, [the old commit](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/b3cafcc20b2f7be1ccbbd857382318b725c726d1#diff-382b3649283911e1a5c64f3ec00e4968L242) should fix the problem, which you described. Additionally, I don't see any problem with `z-index` on the picture. Do you specified `zIndex` parameter somewhere? Which real problem you have with `z-index`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **the latest** version of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). It's currently 4.14.0. The bug with incorrectly addressing of `query` field of the Searching Dialog should be already fixed in free jqGrid 4.14.0 (see [the old commit](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/b3cafcc20b2f7be1ccbbd857382318b725c726d1#diff-382b3649283911e1a5c64f3ec00e4968L242)).